Is there a $\gamma^{5}$ in $d$-dimensional Clifford Algebra?
I was trying to compute the EW vacuum polarization
$$i\Pi_{LL}^{\mu\nu}=(-1)\mu^{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}e^{2}∫\frac{d^{d}k}{(2\pi)^{d}}\frac{Tr\bigl(i\gamma^{\mu}(iP_{L})i(\not{k}+m_{i})(i\gamma^{\nu})P_{L}i(\not{p}+\not{k}+m_{j})  \bigr)}{[k^{2}-m_{i}^{2}][(p+k)^{2}-m^{2}_{j}]}.$$
However I don't know how to proceed since I do not know if there is an analogue definition of $\gamma^{5}$ in $d<4$ dimension. If it exists, then what are the relevant trace relations for them? I can't find a good reference for that

This is a classic problem in dimensional regularization, the definition of $\gamma^5$ in $d$ dimensions always has some inconsistencies. One usually sets $\gamma^5=i\gamma^0\gamma^1\gamma^2\gamma^3$ regardless of the actual number of dimensions; see Sec. 19.2 of Peskin & Schroeder.

Interesting, I'll take a look thank you

Suffice to say you can still do a majority of the calculation (I've done similar) because the problematic pieces are just traces over gamma matrices that include the fifth gamma matrix. However these just appear as coefficients of the tensor integrals that you arrive at by pulling momenta out of the traces and evaluating the integrals. I know this doesn't necessarily resolve what pieces are not relevant due to the traces but at that point you can choose a prescription based on your problem.

Do you mean that can be included in terms $\propto p^{\mu}p^{\nu}$ that can be neglected in the massless limit?
